# Can I add a timestamp to a Rules Object Type in Foundry?

Tags: palantir-foundry

I am trying to create a rules object that will return the current date so that we know when it is last modified. Is this possible? If so, what is the best way to include this field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. When creating the Rules and Proposals, be sure to include fields with timestamps, such as the Last Modified Timestamp field below.
[image: rule set up page]
In the rules section for Action Types, which will affect either Proposals or Rules, be sure to change the timestamp field to “Current Time” rather than an input field.
[image: Showing changed timestamp]
If you do that, every time you submit an action type it will add the current time to the Rule or Proposal.